# MQ queue should allow file transfers up to 5MB

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am new to com.ibm.mq API (1.6 version). I have been given a task where currently, I have standalone java application on Mac OS which downloads the messages from the server. Right now, the message limit has been set to default which is 4 KB. This need to be increased up to 5 MB. I have read on the forums that we can increase the MQ Queue size up to 100 MB. Can you please suggest me steps or refer to the link where I can get the details for fulfilling my requirements.

Comment: Go to the MQ knowledge centre and search for message size; would also advise use JMS2.0 with MQ v8;
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.con.doc/q081980_.htm?lang=en

Answer (score 3):

You need to increase the max message length (MAXMSGL) three places:  on the QMgr object, the local queue where your application will ultimately put messages and on the channel object.  More information is available at the WMQ Knowledge Center.  Here is a link to the properties for the QMgr (queue manager) object:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.explorer.doc/e_properties_qmanager.htm?lang=en